# 'git' is not a git command when trying to run alias

Tags: git

I have configured alias:

`git config --global aliast.tttt 'git status'`
and when I run: `git config --get-regexp alias` I can see: `alias.tttt git status`

then why when I run `git tttt` then get error: `expansion of alias 'tttt' failed; 'git' is not a git command`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+expansion+of+alias+failed+git+is+not+a+git+command

Comment: Simply `git config --global aliast.tttt status` or using shell (note the exclamation mark): `git config --global aliast.tttt '!git status'`

Comment: same, `expansion of alias 'tttt' failed; 'git' is not a git command`

Comment: Please show `git config aliast.tttt` ?

Comment: it returns `git status` but `git tttt` returns `expansion of alias 'tttt' failed; 'git' is not a git command`

Comment: `git config aliast.tttt` must not be `git status`. It must be either simple `status` or shell command `!git status`